# How to upload a Python script in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

There is an error while I upload my zip while in Azure and the error shows there is `no such directory`

My zip file is on desktop by name model and the pkl file through which I made zip file is in folder outputs which is also on desktop.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pickle

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    sys.path.insert(0,"C:\\Users\\SahilAseeja\\Desktop\\model")  
    model=pickle.load(open("C:\\Users\\SahilAseeja\\Desktop\\model\\model_2019_08_09_12_56_55_756.pkl", 'rb'))
    pred = model.predict(dataframe1)
    return pd.DataFrame([pred[0]])
```

I want to make  run zip file in azure, so I want the error accounting in this code

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which azure service you're using, web app or webjobs etc.

And then in azure, it can not find the local path like "C:\Users\SahilAseeja\Desktop\model". You should consider upload your file to azure storage like azure file storage or azure blob storage.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as a comment? I'm not sure though.